# Capturing multiple groups in a regex does not return any result

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text-mining

I have a python function

```
def regex(series, regex):
    series = series.str.extract(regex)
    series1 = series.dropna()
    return (series1)
```

Aim to match the regex with the pattern as below:

- anything with 'no' followed by (group of words) or a 'not' should not be matched. Below is the regex used in a python function:

  `result = regex(df['col'],r'(^(?!.*\bno\b.*\b(text|sample text )\b)(?!.*\b(text|sample text)\b .*not).+$)')`

I do not get any results (just an empty data frame)when applying the regex in a function, [image]

but testing the regex in this link works well https://regex101.com/r/Epq0Ns/21

Comment: that regex101 pattern doesn't work, it matches every sentence, including those with "no"

Comment: @sweaver2112 posted an updated link. pls check

Comment: Use `^(?!(?=.*\b(?:sample )?text\b)(?=.*\bnot?\b)).+`

Comment: @ctwheels these text are my initial results, later I would need to add more terms to the group (text, sample text, text book, note book) etc. In general, trying to eliminate negative sentences: Eg: 1. No text book found 2. notebook not found, etc

Comment: @sagar the above pattern is faster than yours regardless. Just check for the occurrence of `no` or `not` and `text` or `sample text` separately. Don't combine them.

Comment: @ctwheels There would be many occurrences I would have to match and with your code, I would have to keep doing for all possible combinations. I am just curious why isn't it working in my python function, also if there is a multiple grouping that can be done, just prefix with 'no' and suffix with 'not'

Comment: @sagar it not much different than your expression. It's just simplifying it by checking negation and words separately. `^(?!(?=.*\b(?:(?:sample )?text(?: book)?|notebook)\b)(?=.*\bnot?\b)).+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

For simplicity sake, you can actually just use lists and list comprehension to build simple regular expression patterns.

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/uvmoaU)

```
import re

negations = ["no", "not"]
words = ["text", "sample text", "text book", "notebook"]
sentences = [
    "first sentence with no and sample text",
    "second with a text but also a not",
    "third has a no, a text and a not",
    "fourth alone is what is neeeded with just text",
    "keep putting line here no"
] 

for sentence in sentences:
    negationsRegex = re.compile(r"\b(?:" + "|".join([re.escape(n) for n in negations]) + r")\b")
    wordsRegex = re.compile(r"\b(?:" + "|".join([re.escape(w) for w in words]) + r")\b")
    if not (re.search(negationsRegex, sentence) and re.search(wordsRegex, sentence)):
        print sentence
```

**Above code outputs**:

```
fourth alone is what is neeeded with just text
keep putting line here no
```

---

### Explanation

The code compiles a joined list of regex-escaped words ensuring word boundaries are set. The resulting regular expressions generated (given the lists `negations` and `words) will be as follows:

```
\b(?:no|not)\b
\b(?:text|sample text|text book|notebook)\b
```

The `if` statement then checks to see if both generated patterns (the negation regex and word regex) match the sentence. If both expressions don't match (one or both don't match), then the string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the same flags you use on regex101 - change the line in the function to:

```
series = series.str.extract(regex, re.M | re.S)
```

or

```
series = series.str.extract(regex, flags=re.M|re.S)
```

I would have tested, if you had the code for the input definition.